# Build with gcc binary issue: Wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 on Solaris

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, solaris, ld, ldd

I need to build a simple app to run on Solaris 8 64 bit system.
The Solaris system is on production and do not have developer packages installed.

For this purpose I maintained (after hard work of following manuals and experimenting) to build a gcc cross compiler on Fedora 24 64 bit machine and successfully built a hello world program that runs well on target Solaris machine.

The actually needed app was built also successful after another long time of research after includes and libraries.

Unfortunately, the app does not run on target system because of wrong library linked by ld, it is trying to load both 32 and 64 bit libdga.so.1:

```
ldd getIdleTime_sparc
        libX11.so.4 =>   /usr/lib/64/libX11.so.4
        libXext.so.0 =>  /usr/lib/64/libXext.so.0
        libdga.so.1 =>   /usr/openwin/lib/libdga.so.1  - wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/64/libc.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/64/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/64/libnsl.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/64/libdl.so.1
        libdga.so.1 =>   /usr/openwin/lib/sparcv9/libdga.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /usr/lib/64/libmp.so.2
        /usr/platform/SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi-Engine/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
```

I did not succeed to find how to exclude this wrong ELF.

Any suggestions and help are appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: What are your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32` environment variables set to?  I suspect that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/usr/openwin/bin`.  Not a good idea for a 64-bit binary...

Comment: The output of `elfdump -d getIdleTime_sparc` would also be helpful here.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH contained /usr/openwin/lib and also /usr/lib , I changed it to /usr/openwin/lib/sparcv9 and /usr/lib/sparcv9 , now ldd output lists only 64 bit libs and program run successfully, thanks @AndrewHenle.

Comment: @Tony If you put `/usr/openwin/lib/sparcv9` and `/usr/lib/sparcv9` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that means 32-bit binaries won't run.  That's why Solaris has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7md6/index.html : *Each environment variable can be specified with a _32 or _64 suffix. This makes the environment variable specific, respectively, to 32-bit or 64-bit processes and overrides any non-suffixed version of the environment variable that may be in effect.*

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewHenle, it is ok, I replaced the environment only for my app, not system-wide.